# Concatenating fields in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, concatenation, amazon-redshift

I am doing this to create a key in Redshift SQL
is there an issue with this code? (it's not populating with the name piece)

```
concat((name)+'-'+left(address_zip,5)) as key
```

Answer (score 3):

```sql
CONCAT(CONCAT(name, '-'), left(address_zip, 5)) as key
```

or using `||` operator:

```sql
name || '-' || left(address_zip,5) as key
```

you can find the documentation here :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CONCAT.html